# Place sprite in relation to point on screen, not on map

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, screen

In Cocos2D, I would like a sprite placed on a screen coordinate, not a map coordinate. I thought I could get by using convertToNodeSpace, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

I thought this should place a sprite in the middle of my iPad screen:

`selectionScreenOverlaySprite.position = [self convertToNodeSpace:CGPointMake(512, 384)];`

But it doesn't. It also places it in a different place depending on the size of my map. Does anyone know what I should be using?  I've also tried: convertToWorldSpace, convertToNodeSpaceAR, and convertToWorldSpaceAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGSize wins = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
[yourSprite setPosition:CGPointMake(wins.width / 2, wins.height / 2)];
```

This is better than using hard-coded values because it will work regardless of resolution.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful to know, but it is still placing it in a different position depending on the size of the map. Also, I may be viewing the opposite side of the map when it is placed, which may add to this problem.

Comment: What is this map of which you speak? Is it the layer to which the sprite is added? If so, that will affect its position. Add it to a layer that has the same bounds as the screen.

Comment: Okay I understand, but that will also force a different order of the sprite in relation to everything else, right? It's being added to self, which is the CCLayer that renders the map.

Comment: When adding sprites to a layer, you can specify their ordering with the `z:` parameter. `[self addChild:someSprite z:0]`

Comment: I know about z ordering, but if I add it to another layer, can I still specify a z order that will make it appear in front of a higher layer?

Comment: No. The z ordering only applies to children that are in the same layer as the child you are adding. It is similar to `insertSubview:atIndex:` in that you cannot make it appear behind the view to which it is added and you cannot make it appear in front of a view that is sitting on top of the view to which it was added.

Comment: What is strange is that I just remembered that I have a sprite added to the center of the screen when I leave the map, and that works correctly, and it seems to work the same exact way.  I need to investigate this issue.

Comment: Do you think it's because I'm calling the action method from init?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I was calling convertToNodeSpace from init, which is bad because it's not added to the parent node yet. For some reason if I call it right before return self, it works fine. But I really liked your simple yet insightful comment so I will give you a check. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate that, and I'm glad you figured out your problem!